# Create dll using Perceptual SDK

Tags: dll, intel

Good day!

I runned exapmles MyFirstDll and FaceAnalysis. They work fine and now i want to create dll with PSDK functionality.

**PercDll.cpp:**

```
extern "C++" CALLBACKPROC_API void Start(void)
{
    MainCore* core_ = new MainCore();
    core_->ToGo();
}
```

**MainCore.h:**

```
class MainCore
{
public:
    MainCore()    {    }
    int ToGo()
    {
        UtilPipeline* pipeline = new UtilPipeline(); /* 1 */
        return 0;
    }
};
```

If i commit string /* 1 */ all builds and works fine. But  when i uncommit string /* 1 */ i look errors:

Error 1    error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all(void)" (?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in libpxcutils_d.lib(util_pipeline_raw.obj)    c:\Users\i\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Perceptual10\Perceptual10\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)

Error 2    error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)" (??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ)already defined in libpxcutils_d.lib(util_pipeline_raw.obj)    c:\Users\i\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Perceptual10\Perceptual10\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)

Error 4    error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found c:\users\i\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Perceptual10\Debug\Perceptual10.dll    1

What's this? I am searching the solutio​n for a long time. Help please to fix it.
Thank you!